# Using while to grab the next not null value

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

I have this Pandas dataframe in Python which is a list of all actions that have been made by a team in a football match. If there's a score resulting of a play, I have the amount of points scored in the column "Score", otherwise this column remains empty:

| play_id | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 8 | 3 |
| 9 |  |
| 10 |  |

I would like to create a new column called "next_score" based on those conditions:

- If the play results in points, I want to grab those points
- If the play doesn't result in points (i.e. the value is null), I want to grab the next point scored.

The table would look like this:

| play_id | Score | next_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 6 |
| 2 |  | 6 |
| 3 |  | 6 |
| 4 | 6 | 6 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 |
| 6 |  | 3 |
| 7 |  | 3 |
| 8 | 3 | 3 |
| 9 |  | 6 |
| 10 | 6 | 6 |

I have been using this code:

```
next_score = []
for point in df['Score']:
    if point == "":
        while point+1 == "":
            continue
        else:
            next_score.append(point)
            break
    else:
        next_score.append(point)
df['next_score'] = next_score
```

But that gives me the same results as the column "Score". I'm not able to tell my code to grab the next scoring results. Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas comes with batteries included:

```
df['next_score'] = df['Score'].fillna(method='backfill')
```

Comment: My god, I spent so much time trying to make it myself, many thanks for your answer!